# Laravel Custom Morph Relationship with custom table structure

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following table structure:

```
Tokens
- type ( Flag Indicating that if its a Users token or company's token )
- user_company_id (User or Company Id )

Users
- id
- username
- password

Companies
- id
- username
- password
```

Im trying to create the relationship from the token to get the user or the company based on the **type** flag.

I know that I should have a different modeling, but this database is up and running and I cant change their structure.

How can I do this?

Im trying to figure it out but no success until now =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this (make sure the namespace and model names are correct):

Token Model:

```php
class Token extends Model
{
    public function tokenable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

User Model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Token', 'tokenable', 'type', 'user_company_id');
    }
}
```

Company Model:

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Token', 'tokenable', 'type', 'user_company_id');
    }
}
```

Notice the third (`type`) and fourth (`user_company_id`) argument in the `morphMany` method call, those are optional but in your case, these are required because you've custom field names in your database. Check the documentation to learn [how to retrieve relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).